# Setting up ViewController for UIViewController, with a Table View, connecting to Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I know how to connect parse to a UITableViewController using PFQueryTableViewController. My problem is that instead of using a TableViewController, I'm wanting to use a ViewController with a Table View embedded within it which is connected to Parse.

Also, I'll noted that I'm working in Swift. Can anyone provide support in how that is set up within xCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an incredibly simple solution (well, it combines two things I already know anyways). I opened a view controller, threw a containment view within that. I deleted the view controller that it naturally created, and then I embedded a table view controller that I already had set up (control + clicked). Now, I've got my tableviewcontroller within my viewcontroller.

Hopefully this helps someone else down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Basic outline to address this scenario:

- drag a View Controller to the storyboard
- drag a Table View into the View Controller
- select the Table View and Go to Prototype cells properties in Xcode and increment to 1

  - Click on the prototype cell and assign it a cell identifier e.g. "cell"
  - In the code of the View Controller do the following:
    a) Ensure declaration of class includes all required table delegates
    b) Implement all functions required by the table view delegates

I highly advise on looking at a tutorial that shows how to do this step by step (forgetting about Parse in the mean time). Parse UI simplifies this process but hides a lot of steps that may be necessary to grasp the concept.

Comment: Thanks, @ksa_coder. I've done tutorials on everything that you've mentioned. I'm simply having trouble connecting the Table View to Parse...